# Where to add 'strict_types' for PHP7 in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I am starting a new project in symfony and i have switched from PHP56 to PHP7. As per guidelines you have to add following to reflect new features of PHP7

```
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);

// Rest of the code...
```

Where should i put 'strict_type' in my new symfony project to avoid writing 'strict_type' in each file, so that new features of PHP7 should be reflected globally throughout the project?

Comment: I use it like in one line like this `<?php declare(strict_types=1);` so it takes the least amount of space possible.

Comment: I know you can write like this but i was wondering if there's a shortcut to avoid redundant piece of code in every file, since i am using php7 throughout.

Comment: Yes, I know, but zerkms already replied that it's a per-file directive so I just wanted to add how we use it to so it at least takes less space :)

Comment: i guess i would have to take this approach then!!

Comment: If you could declare `strict_types` globally, them probably 97% of 3rd party libraries, packages would crash. That's why it's declared per file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a per-file directive, so you must put it in every file.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php